# How to use the FontAwesome Icon Library in React?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, font-awesome-5, react-font-awesome

I have a React project that uses FontAwesome icons. To keep the code DRY, I wanted to keep my icon imports in a separate file using the Icon Library, per the guide here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/javascript-api/setup/library.

I added a `fontawesome.js` file with the following code:

```
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";

import { faCode, faHighlighter } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

library.add(faCode, faHighlighter);
```

and imported `fontawesome.js` into my `index.js`. Then I tried rendering `faCode` to my `Icon.js` component:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

export default function Icon() {
  return (
    <div>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'fa-code']} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

only to encounter the following error:

```
Could not find icon {prefix: "fas", iconName: "fa-code"}
```

I think I'm missing an import here. The documentation wasn't entirely clear on what to do after the Library has been set up. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you replace `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'fa-code']} />` by `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'faCode']} />` ?

Comment: Here is another way to cache font awesome in react. find it out from this [LINK](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react)

Comment: @antoineso didn't work for me :/

Comment: @hrghafoori this worked for me! seems that I was crawling up the wrong documentation. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Feel free to post as an answer to mark as accepted.

Comment: try to put code instead of faCode.

Comment: @mmz your welcome, Please click on "top arrow" to the left of my comment. So the next person who sees this thread can get the correct answer faster.

Comment: @hrghafoori seems that I need 15+ rep to vote on comments. Not there yet. My apologies, and thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to cache font awesome in react. find it out from this [LINK](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react)

Answer (score 0):

you need to import the solid (with 'fas' tag) icons from fontawesome:

npm i @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
or
yarn add @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons